# JS Array not recognized as an array in Google Apps script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am writing what should be a simple HTML form for users to make a reservation.  However, having difficulty doing something I've done many times before - getting data from a GSheet and presenting it in an HTML form. Code snippets:

```
**Server side**
//Getting data from spreadsheet; expecting it to be an array of arrays.

function  getMembers(){
  const url = "https://my gsheet url"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Members");
  const row = ws.getLastRow()
  const memberData = ws.getRange(2,1,row-1,7).getValues(); 
  const array = JSON.stringify(memberData);  //EDIT...helps get data to client side
  return  //array; //this data to be passed to browser when called.  Type Error?

//Log(memberData) = //Looks like an array to me...
//[1,"Simmie","Smith","Simmie Smith","2020-01-01T05:00:00.000Z","temp","53120-1"],
//[2,"Fred","Williams","Fred Williams","2020-01-01T05:00:00.000Z","temp","53120-2"],
//[3,"Carleton","Johnson","Carleton Johnson","2020-01-01T05:00:00.000Z","temp","53120-3"],
//[4,"Caroll","Williams","Caroll Williams","2020-01-01T05:00:00.000Z","temp","53120-4"],
//[5,"Gabby","Williams","Gabby Williams","2020-01-01T05:00:00.000Z","temp","53120-5"]


//EDIT HtmlService code
function doGet(e){
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Reservations HTML')
    .evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

Calling the above server function when page loads so that member name can be presented in a select dropdown and other info from the array used elsewhere.

```
**Browser JS**

function getMemberData(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateMembersDD).getMembers(); 
}

function populateMembersDD(data){
 console.log(data) //undefined - same result FFox or Chrome..
 memberInfo = data.filter(function(row){return true});
```

not getting any further than that because data is not passing to browser in a format with which I can apply necessary methods to get data into dropdown. Have tried various methods (slice, filter etc) to convert data into an array but none have worked. I suspect a type error, as though server function is not producing an object in array format.  But I cannot figure out why.  Have read many similar questions/answers on Stack but none have solved my problem.  Help much appreciated as I am 24 hours in on solution experiments.  Have many other apps where this basic code pattern works totally fine...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using a forEach loop to build html table and date/time comes through as null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61803459/using-a-foreach-loop-to-build-html-table-and-date-time-comes-through-as-null)

Comment: If you have a date in there then that’s the problem. You can read about data restrictions in client to server communication in the guides section of the documentation

Comment: *Help much appreciated as I am 24 hours in on solution experiments.* Reading all the relevant documentation would've costed less.

Comment: @TheMaster Recently [tag:google-apps-script-html-service] was created and i think that in this it might be better than [tag:google-apps-script-web-application] because the question doesn't include how the client-side code is created (there is no `doGet`, etc.)

Comment: @Rubén google-apps-script-web-application was supposed to encompass all web applications, including apps in sidebar or modal dialogs as long as it included web content. I think  the new tag is not necessary. Or google-apps-script-web-application could be renamed google-apps-script-html-service or the both could be merged or html-service to subsume web-apps. I believe two tags for such closely related  services are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you @Cooper and Master. It was that date field.   Btw, I had tried earlier to stringify the array on the server side.  That helped get the data to the client but I still got errors when I tried to apply array methods   (filter, etc...) to the data on the client side.  And I would love to understand why the errors...data clearly not recognized as an array...Not sure why but, more importantly, removing the date from the array completely solved the original problem.  Thanks again...

Comment: @cwilly3 Because the data passed is of "string" type. You need to json.parse it back to a array  "object" type client side.

Comment: If you managed to solve your original question, think about [https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer](Answering your Own Question) to help some other people that may be having the same problem.

Comment: Thanks again @master.  definitely sounds right though have not tried it...all working well without that date...